# npx babel-node foo takes 10 seconds to run every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, npm, npx

Running the following command takes about 10 seconds to run every time, extremely slow:

```
$ npx babel-node foo.js
```

Wondering what techniques I can use to improve performance, such as perhaps caching the transpilation of the modules in some way, or doing some sort of file watching. By 10 seconds I mean it takes 10 seconds to even enter a script that only has this in it:

```
import React from 'react'

console.log('here')
```

So the script is not complicated, just the transpilation is probably complicated.

Comment: That's because `npx` reinstalls package each time. Just install `babel-node` as dev dependency and run it from npm script

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config loglevel verbose
```

And try running babel-node as dev dependency / global if the first line doesn’t make the issue obvious!